# zuhanyozik vs sibilant verbs in hungarian

Tags: hungarian

In my book, there is a rule to conjugate verbs that are both sibilant and -ik verbs. For instance alszik conjugates in present as:

> alszom, alszol, alszik, alszunk, alszotok, alszanak.

Next, it is asked to conjugate zuhanyozik. I can see that it is also a sibilant and -ik, but the conjugation is

> zyhanyozom, zuhanyozol, zuhanyozik, zuhanyozunk, zuhanyoz**tok**, zuhanyoz**nak**

The conjugation for ti and ők are different compared to alszik. In fact, it conjugates exactly the same as találkozik. Is there a rule for how to recognize and conjugate appropriately the sibilants + ik verbs? Do I have to learn them by heart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forms *alsz**o**tok* and *alsz**a**nak* have a linking vowel because "lsz" is a consonant cluster, not because sz is a sibilant. The stem of *zuhanyozik* doesn't end in a consonant cluster, so *zuhanyoztok* and *zuhanyoznak* have no linking vowel. A linking vowel occurs also after consonant clusters ending in non-sibilant consonants, or after a single t.

Linking vowels in the present tense are explained in 2.3 of this guide: "[Learn the Hungarian Present Tense (in 30 Minutes](https://www.catchbudapest.com/learn-hungarian-present-tense/)", *Catch Budapest.*

It gives the following examples:

| mond- | segít- | küld- |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mond-otok | segít-etek | küld-ötök |
| mond-anak | segít-enek | küld-enek |